# Jquery fill meta attr 'content' with img src

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook og tag...

```
<meta property="og:image" content="whatever.jpg"/>
```

And I'd like to change the whatever.jpg to a image on the page contained in a div with an id #ok

```
<div id="ok">
<img src="saveme.jpg" />
</div>
```

so i'd end up with

```
<meta property="og:image" content="saveme.jpg"/>
```

and ideas? been searching aroundthe api and havent found anything which does this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you

```
 $('meta[property="og:image"]').attr('content',$('#ok img').attr('src'));
```

An example is here http://jsfiddle.net/RMd27/

Comment: 100 thank yous, this basicly does what I asked for, tho it appears that the og tag pulls the image before the js loads so the original images still show, looks like I'll have to find another way.

Comment: no problem @user1110237 if this is the answer dont forget to mark it as answer accepted :) and good luck

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have one `meta` tag with the `og:image` property:

```
$('meta[property="og:image"]').attr('content',$('#ok').find('img').attr('src'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('meta[property="og:image"]').attr("content",$("#ok > img").attr("src"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be setting any OpenGraph data via JavaScript, since it tends to be crawled by search engines and social networking sites, and those don't have JavaScript (in other words, what they see will be the unaltered value). Depending on how you're setting the OpenGraph values, you might want to change your PHP to output the correct image that you want for that particular page.